# How to check if a MPEG transport stream file contains sound or not?

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg

I have the following .ts file. I don't hear any sound when I open it in a video player. But I am not sure what is wrong with it. Is it that the file does not contain any sound? Or it is because my video player does not understand the sound info it?

https://easyupload.io/109ixb

Answer (score 0):

`ffprobe -hide_banner -i your_filename`
This shows all streams contained;
in your case, output of `ffprobe -hide_banner -i 0.ts` shows that there is only video data:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '0.ts': Duration: 00:00:10.01, start: 0.083422, bitrate: 3940 kb/s 
Program 1
Stream #0:0[0x102]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
```